# How would one copy only the first x lines of a *csv* file into a new *csv* file via the cmd in windows

Tags: csv, cmd

How would one copy only the first `x` number lines of a `csv` file into a new `csv` file via the `cmd` on Windows?

`head -N file.csv > newfile.csv`
this is the solution for Mac OS terminal, can someone please tell the same for windows `cmd`?

Comment: `powershell Get-Content -Path "file.csv" ^| Select-Object -First 10 > newfile.csv`

Comment: Why is it important, that this is a **csv** file? BTW, the version for MacOS would be `-n`, not `-N`.

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY want to do it via batch there are several methods for doing it here https://serverfault.com/questions/490841/how-to-display-the-first-n-lines-of-a-command-output-in-windows-the-equivalent

Or the way I used to do it back in the days before Powershell was via the GNU port of the *nix `Head` command which can be downloaded from https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

with which you'd extract the first (say 10) lines of text using

```
Head -n 10 file.csv > newfile.csv
```

But the easier native way IMHO is to just doing it using Powershell. In which case

```
Import-Csv -Path c:\folder\file.csv -Delimiter "," | 
    Select -First 10 |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\folder\newfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

would do what you need.

Comment: Shouldn't the GNU command be `head` instead of `Head`? Also, the `-10` form is considered obsolete. For compatibility, `-n 10` should be used.

Comment: Good point about the `-n 10` syntax... that'll teach me to try writing code from memory with something I've not used in years. :) Corrected.